# Set owner to form from another process form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I have a Form (parent). Also I have handle to the Form (child) from another process. I need to always show the child form on top of the parent and was possible to work with the main form.

It works when we call:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var childForm = new Form();
        childForm.Show(this);
    }
}
```

Also, if the main form closes, the child form from another process will continue to work.

I try used pinvoke SetParent() function, but it set child form as MDI.

Comment: You can use childForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: I can't. Сhild form is already open and is in a another process!

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't ask new questions by editing existing ones. Please deal with one question at a time. If you want to ask a new question do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) passing `GWL_HWNDPARENT` as the index.

```
SetWindowLongPtr(OwnedWnd, GWL_HWNDPARENT, OwnerWnd);
```

You may need to manually bring the owned window in front of the owner window in the z-order, because simply calling the function above will not make that happen.

Comment: That's what SetParent() already does.  The OP wants to turn it into a child window, WS_CHILD style flag.  Hmm.

Comment: @HansPassant No. `SetParent` changes the parent. The code here modifies the owner. Not that MS made it easy to know that with the name `GWL_HWNDPARENT`. But this is just the overloaded `hWndParent`  argument from `CreateWindow`. And it seems to me that the asker wants to modify the owner. That word appears in the question title, and then there is this text *I need to always show the child form on top of the parent* which implies owner rather than parent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. It helped, but there are some problems. When you call SetWindowLongPtr child form disappears from the taskbar. If you remove her focus and select again, it appears in the taskbar again. How to make so that it does not disappear from the taskbar when calling SetWindowLongPtr?
Can I do that this child form was always on top of all opened child forms from the main form?

Comment: Owned windows don't have taskbar buttons. Add WS_EX_APPWINDOW extended style. That's a different question though. I think I answered the one you asked.